# Fix the Row containing Text

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Is it possible to fix the row which has some text in it so that the text don't move from its place if a new row or column is inserted above it.

Regards,
Salman Khan

Answer (score 0):

Try using freeze panes it will help you out